# Why is a function literal returning an int not assignable to a function returning interface{}?

Tags: go

I couldn't reason why this code does [not](https://play.golang.org/p/yOzukoJhJ4N) compile:

```
package main

import "math/rand"

type ooThinAir func() interface{}

func Int() ooThinAir {
    return func() int {
        return rand.Intn(100)
    }
}
func main() {
}

// fails with: cannot use func literal (type func() int) as type ooThinAir in return argument
```

given, according to the GoLang Spec, [that](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) all types implement the empty interface `interface{}`. Why is the function literal *not* assignable to type `ooThinAir`?

Comment: `ooThinAir` is not `interface{}`. If it were (https://play.golang.org/p/x_pVwLdf3NS), that would be OK, but it's not.

Comment: A `func() int` is not assignable to `func() interface{}`. Use this: `return func() interface{} { return rand.Intn(100) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Any type is assignable to interface.

A type that *includes* interface is a different story.

`[]int` is not assignable to `[]interface{}`

`func() int` is not assignable to `func() interface{}`

You have to make the *whole thing* into an `interface{}` and then use reflection to handle the result.

Because `[]int` is assignable to `interface{}`, and `func() int` is assignable to `interface{}`.